# How to conditionally load a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net UserControl that can be added multiple times to a page.  On this UserControl I am using a jQuery plugin that I would only like to load once.  I am using the following piece of code to conditionally load jQuery itself:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    // load jquery 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "/_layouts/SprocketValidator/jQuery.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
} else {
    //already loaded
}
```

Would there be an equivalent for checking if a jQuery plugin is undefined?  The plugin I am using is the [digitalBush masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

Comment: Once jQuery is loaded, all you need to do is check: [code]if (!plugin){ $.getScript('pluginurl');}[/code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if (typeof jQuery.fn.mask == 'undefined')
```

jquery-methods (plugin-methods usually too) are stored as properties of `$.fn`, so you'll need to check if a method available inside the plugin(e.g. `mask()`) is known as member of `$.fn`

Comment: This looks promising but where would I put this?  I tried dropping it in right after the code I had above but I get this error: `jQuery is not defined` in the condition you provided.  I'm guessing that jQuery just hasn't had a chance to load yet, but where would be the proper place to put this?

Comment: you'll better use document.write() to inject the `<script/>`'s (jquery and the plugin) into the DOM. Otherwise (when using DOM-methods) there will be no guarantee that the script's be loaded the usual way/order(as if they have been hardcoded)

Comment: Or: observe the load-event of the jquery-script and load the plugin when it fires.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like **YepNope.js** that you can find [here](http://yepnopejs.com). And then, you can write your javascript like that:

```
yepnope({
  test: window.JSON,
  nope: "/_layouts/SprocketValidator/jQuery.js",
  complete: function () {
    var data = window.JSON.parse('{ "json" : "string" }');
  }
});
```